# Guardar variables desde un txt

Tags: c

Pues no se como guardar bien las variables de un .txt para manipularlas de manera eficiente y me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma sencilla de hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo:

```
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char linea1[100],linea2[100],tab[100],tab1[100],nombre[100],apellido[100],apellido2[100];
float a[10],b[10],c[10],d[10],e[10];
FILE *f1;
f1=fopen("hola.txt","r");

int i=0;
while(!feof(f1)){
    fscanf(f1,"%s %s %s %f %f %f %f %f  ",nombre,apellido,apellido2,a,b,c,d,e);

}
fclose(f1);
}
```

y esto es lo que hay en el.txt:

Fernando Perez Perez 3.4 4.5 8.5 9.0 6.3

Jose Perez Ruiz 7.3 8.2 6.0 7.2 6.8

Manuel Diez Sanchez 5 3.4 6.9 6 4

Comment: Investiga sobre los structs

Answer (score 2):

En C es posible crear estructuras de datos. Las estructuras de datos nos permiten agrupar valores que están relacionados entre sí, por ejemplo la información asociada a un usuario:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[100];
    char apellido1[100];
    char apellido2[100];
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float nota3;
    float nota4;
    float nota5;
} Usuario;
```

Esta sería una traducción más o menos literal partiendo de tu código. Por funcionar, funcionaría, sin embargo no es el diseño más elegante posible. Por ejemplo, la gracia de almacenar varias notas está en poder calcular a posteriori, la media (por poner un ejemplo). Así, con el diseño actual la media habría que calcularla así:

```
Usuario usuario = /* ... */;
float media = (usuario.nota1 + usuario.nota2 + usuario.nota3 + usuario.nota4 + usuario.nota5) / 5;
```

Si en vez de tener 5 notas tienes 20 el problema se complica con demasiada rapidez.

La solución a este tipo de problema pasa por agrupar valores similares en arrays:

```
#define NUM_NOTAS 5
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[100];
    char apellidos[2][100];
    float notas[NUM_NOTAS];
} Usuario;
```

Ahora le cálculo de la media, independientemente de la cantidad de notas que haya, sería así:

```
float media = 0.;
for(int i=0; i<NUM_NOTAS; i++)
    media += usuario.notas[i];
media /= NUM_NOTAS;
```

Y ahora la pregunta clave. ¿Cómo se adaptaría esto a tu código? Pues podría ser así:

```
#define NUM_USUARIOS 10
Usuario usuarios[10];
int num_usuarios = 0;

while (1)
{
    fscanf(f1, "%s %s %s", usuarios[num_usuarios].nombre, usuarios[num_usuarios].apellidos[0], usuarios[num_usuarios].apellidos[1]);
    if (feof(f1)) break;

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_NOTAS; i++)
        fscanf(f1, "%f", &usuarios[num_usuarios].notas[i]);

    num_usuarios++;
}
```

O, si quieres dejarlo un poco más compacto:

```
while (1)
{
    Usuario* usuario = &usuarios[num_usuarios];
    fscanf(f1, "%s %s %s", usuario->nombre, usuario->apellidos[0], usuario->apellidos[1]);
    if (feof(f1)) break;

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_NOTAS; i++)
        fscanf(f1, "%f", &usuario->notas[i]);
    num_usuarios++;
}
```

Dos incisos respecto a mis cambios:

1. Ahora el bucle `while` no comprueba `feof`. La razón es que el flag `EOF` no se activa hasta que no se produce una lectura errónea. Es por eso que la comprobación la hago tras el primer `if` (asumo por simplificar que todas las filas, si tienen datos, están bien escritas)
2. El campo que almacena las notas no es un puntero (ni un array), así que hay que usar `&` para obtener su dirección de memoria